# Recommend permission configuration for static files (CSS, JS) being hosted on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have some static files hosted in S3 that I want to use on my website that is hosted through Elastic Beanstalk. Now, I'm trying to understand what would be the most secure permissions to set for my S3 bucket. I need the files to be public/accessible enough to all my website to use the CSS/JS files stored in the bucket, but I don't want it to be accessible for any other reason.

[image]

Above is a screenshot of the permission settings available. Should I leave them all unchecked in order to be able to use the CSS/JS files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to put appropriate [bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2) which limits access to only the few specific objects of yours. You can further limit access to only your website using [referrer condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4). This is not a bullet proof solution for hot linking, but better then nothing.

Once you do this, you can **enable first three options** in public access block,. The forth option must be disabled.

But the best way is to use [CloudFront with S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/) for best results. This allows you to keep your bucket private, and just server your files through CloudFront.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to use the s3 policy generator tool with "s3:PutObject",
"s3:PutObjectAcl",
"s3:GetObject",
"s3:GetObjectAcl",
"s3:DeleteObject", selected and it fixed my issues. I left all of the fields unchecked in my screenshot above. I wasn't able to use cloudfront yet, thats a bit over my head and I wasn't sure where to start. I'll try that in the future once I've gotten the basics down.